# MongoDB - Comment Upvoting/Downvoting with Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to implement an upvote/downvote mechanism for comments (similar to the upvoting/downvoting mechanism found on reddit). I have a separate collection called `commentReputation` and the documents inside can look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5acb6d6034a879655c8819"),
    "commentId" : ObjectId("5e5983102328a83d1a4b541f"),
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2020-02-29T20:37:01.509Z"),
    "upvotes" : [
        ObjectId("5e5983102328a83d1a4b53e7"),
        ObjectId("5e5983102328a83d1a4b53e4")
    ],
    "downvotes" : [
       ObjectId("5e5983102328a83d1a4b53e5")
    ]
}
```

In short: every comment will eventually have it's own `CommentReputation` document (the `CommentReputation` document should be created as soon as someone upvotes/downvotes a comment)

There are 2 case scenarios:

1. The collection is empty meaning that I need to create my very first `CommentReputation` document with a given commentId `x`. In some other part of the project I was using `$setOnInsert` with `{ upsert: true }` but it seems (looking at the documentation) that the aggregation pipeline does not support `$setOnInsert` as for now. Is there another way to deal with this problem?
2. The document is there and the actuall upvoting should occur.

   a) Both `upvotes` and `downvotes` arrays do not contain the `userId` that is trying to upvote thus it gets added to the `upvotes` array without any further actions

   b) The `upvotes` array contains the `userId` that is trying to upvote the comment as a result the `userId` should be REMOVED from the `upvotes` array. (the user already had this comment upvoted and clicked a second time the upvote button which cancels out the upvote)

   c) The `downvotes` array contains the `userId`. In this case the `userId` should be removed from `downvotes` and added to `upvotes`

I'm trying to accomplish the above logic with the `updateOne` method and a aggreagtion pipeline however I'm not sure if this is even possible.

What I currently have is returning a `"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$cond'"`

```
const updateUpvotes = {
  $cond: {
    if: { $elemMatch: { upvotes: ObjectID(userId) } },
    then: { $pull: { upvotes: ObjectID(userId) } },
    else: { $addToSet: { upvotes: ObjectID(userId) } }
  }
};

db.collection(collectionName).updateOne({
   commentId: ObjectID('5e5983102328a83d1a4b541f')
}, [updateUpvotes])
```

Am I overthinking the whole feature? I guess the `1.` problem can be solved by simply creating a `CommentReputation` document (with empty `upvotes` and `downvotes` at the same time the `Comment` document is being created.

Is there a better way of doing this? I would love to have it working inside a single query request. Maybe someone of You guys implemented a similar feature and can give me some hints on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with the following pipeline update but it requires that the upvotes and downvotes arrays exist. even if it's just empty.

```java
var comment_id = ObjectId("5e5983102328a83d1a4b541f");
var user_id = ObjectId("5e5983102328a83d1a4b53e5");

db.commentReputation.update(
    {
        commentId: comment_id
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                upvotes: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $in: [user_id, '$upvotes'] },
                        { $setDifference: ['$upvotes', [user_id]] },
                        { $setUnion: ['$upvotes', [user_id]] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                downvotes: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $in: [user_id, '$downvotes'] },
                        { $setDifference: ['$downvotes', [user_id]] },
                        '$downvotes'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! I will solve the required arays part as I described in the question - create them everytime a comment gets created :)

Comment: @L3M0L alternatively you could do a bulkwrite and batch update another operation before this one which checks to see if the arrays exist and add them if not.